# Converting docker-compose to kubernetes using Kompose

Tags: kubernetes, kompose

Im new to Kubernetes and i saw that there is a way runing Kompose up, but i get this error:

```
root@master-node:kompose --file docker-compose.yml --volumes hostPath up
INFO We are going to create Kubernetes Deployments, Services and PersistentVolumeClaims for your Dockerized application. If you need different kind of resources, use the 'kompose convert' and 'kubectl create -f' commands instead.

FATA Error while deploying application: Error loading config file "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf": open /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf: permission denied

ls -l /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
-rw------- 1 root root 5593 Jun 14 08:59 /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

How can i make this work ?

system info :
ubuntu18
Client Version: version.Info: Major:"1", Minor:"21"

I also tried making it work like that:

```
kompose convert --volumes hostPath
INFO Kubernetes file "postgres-1-service.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "postgres-2-service.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "postgres-1-deployment.yaml" created
INFO Kubernetes file "postgres-2-deployment.yaml" created
kubectl create -f postgres-1-service.yaml,postgres-2-service.yaml,postgres-1-deployment.yaml,postgres-1-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml,postgres-1-claim1-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml,postgres-2-deployment.yaml,postgres-2-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml
```

I get this error only on postgres-1-deployment.yaml and postgres-2-deployment.yaml.

```
service/postgres-1 created
service/postgres-2 created
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-1-claim0 created
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-1-claim1 created
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-2-claim0 created
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "postgres-1-deployment.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.Env: []v1.EnvVar: v1.EnvVar.Value: ReadString: expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte of ...|,"value":true},{"nam|..., bigger context ...|sword"},{"name":"REPMGR_PGHBA_TRUST_ALL","value":true},{"name":"REPMGR_PRIMARY_HOST","value":"postgr|...
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "postgres-2-deployment.yaml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.Env: []v1.EnvVar: v1.EnvVar.Value: ReadString: expects " or n, but found t, error found in #10 byte of ...|,"value":true},{"nam|..., bigger context ...|sword"},{"name":"REPMGR_PGHBA_TRUST_ALL","value":true},{"name":"REPMGR_PRIMARY_HOST","value":"postgr|...
```

example of postgres-1-deployment.yaml :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert --volumes hostPath
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: postgres-1
  name: postgres-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: postgres-1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: /snap/kompose/19/kompose-linux-amd64 convert --volumes hostPath
        kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: postgres-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
          value: "true"
        - name: POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: POSTGRESQL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: adminpassword
        - name: POSTGRESQL_USERNAME
          value: user
        - name: REPMGR_NODE_NAME
          value: postgres-1
        - name: REPMGR_NODE_NETWORK_NAME
          value: postgres-1
        - name: REPMGR_PARTNER_NODES
          value: postgres-1,postgres-2:5432
        - name: REPMGR_PASSWORD
          value: repmgrpassword
        - name: REPMGR_PGHBA_TRUST_ALL
          value: yes
        - name: REPMGR_PRIMARY_HOST
          value: postgres-1
        - name: REPMGR_PRIMARY_PORT
          value: "5432"
        image: bitnami/postgresql-repmgr:11
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: postgres-1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/postgresql
          name: postgres-1-hostpath0
        - mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
          name: postgres-1-hostpath1
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /db4_data
        name: postgres-1-hostpath0
      - hostPath:
          path: /root/ansible/api/posrgres11/cluster
        name: postgres-1-hostpath1
status: {}
```

Is kompose translated deploy.yml files the wrong way ? i did everything like guided on kompose guid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured the issue is Kompose translated env value true without quotes "true"
used this verifier https://kubeyaml.com/